# R: Prediction using glm() gamma family

Tags: r, regression, predict, gamma

I am using glm() function in R with link= log to fit my model. I read on various websites that fitted() returns the value which we can compare with the original data as compared to the predict(). 
I am facing some problem while fitting the model.

```
data<-read.csv("training.csv")
data$X2 <- as.Date(data$X2, format="%m/%d/%Y")
data$X3 <- as.Date(data$X3, format="%m/%d/%Y")
data_subset <- subset(...)
attach(data_subset)

#define variable
Y<-cbind(Y)
X<-cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6,X7,X8,X9,X10,X11,X12,X14)

# correlation among variables
cor(Y,X)

model <- glm(Y ~ X , data_subset,family=Gamma(link="log"))
summary(model)

detach(data_subset)

validation_data<-read.csv("validation.csv")

validation_data$X2 <- as.Date(validation_data$X2, format="%m/%d/%Y")
validation_data$X3 <- as.Date(validation_data$X3, format="%m/%d/%Y")

attach(validation_data)
predicted_valid<-predict(model, newdata=validation_data)
```

I am not sure how does predict work with gamma log link. I want to transform the predicted values so that it can be compared with the original data. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `type="response"` to your `predict` call, to get predictions on the response scale. See `?predict.glm`.

```
predict(model, newdata=*, type="response")
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like `fitted` doesn't work the way you seem to think it does.

You probably want to use `predict` there, since you seem to want to pass it data.

see `?fitted` vs `?predict`

Comment: even if i use predict() I am facing the same issue. Predict also produces output which has no of samples equal to training data. Does it have to do anything with the attach or detach?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `attach` or `detach`, but for other reasons I'd strongly advise you to avoid using `attach` and `detach`. Where `data=` arguments exist, use them, and more generally use `with`. It means a little more typing, but it will save you a lot of pain later. You must use exactly the right argument names (and predict is a particular bugbear if your new data doesn't have identical column names to the original, though I don't think you have that problem there).

Comment: @glen_b Thanks a lot for helping me. I am getting an error  1.'newdata' had 2496 rows but variables found have 1639 rows     2.In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = 1, type = ifelse(type ==  :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading

Comment: @glen_b I was using X<- cbind(data_subset$X1, data_subset$X2..) and after i changed it to X<-cbind(X1, X2...) I am no longer getting an error. I have a question, how to i transform the predicted value so that it will be comparable to the original data